# The value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Respected all.

I was going through [this paper](http://www.ijmsi.org/Papers/Volume.3.Issue.4/D034025027.pdf) in which the author stated that he had derived the value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}$ as $\frac{22431 \pi^3}{579292}$. Although I am confused about the result so obtained.

I tried to get the value of $\zeta(3)$ and the above result in Wolfram Alpha, but the answers are not showing equal.

If the result is not appropriate, where is the mistake or misunderstanding that I could not find out ? Can someone please clear my doubt regarding this ?

Thanks in advance

==============

**Edit**: The doubt is clear now. Thank you all for your kind help.

Comment: The paper is a load of nonsense: it was published in the "International Journal of Mathematics and Statistics Invention". This is a predatory open-access journal. Its motto is "you pay, we'll publish".

Comment: I wonder if there is a question on this site about recognizing such bogus articles/journals in general - would be nice to reference that in questions like this.

Comment: @sil Jeffrey Beall kept a list of predatory open access journals. This is no longer on the web (I believe he was prevailed on to remove it) but you should be able to find it on various web archives.

Comment: Re the question itself, frankly I do not understand the upvotes. I typed `zeta(3)` in a search engine and the **first** link I got is to the WP page on Apéry's constant, which fully answers the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The paper is indeed nonsense. The first incorrect (or misleading) line is "Hence the addition of these infinite series must be a multiple of $\pi^3$". It's either misleading (in the trivial sense that anything is a multiple of $\pi^3$), or incorrect: from $a-b=3x$ you can't deduce that $a+b$ is a multiple of $3$ in any sensible way. Anyway, why on earth did the author pick those two particular terms to use as the difference? Any fractions which had difference $\frac{1}{32}$ should have worked, if this method is valid.

In fact the infinite sum is about 1.20206, and the fraction is about 1.20061.

---

I should add that the first warning sign of the paper (other than its journal) is the following line in the introduction:

> $\pi=\frac{22}{7}$ has been taken into consideration.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Even I was also mislead to the outcome  the way statements were made. But now it is clear. Thank you once again \

Comment: In particular, the error with the choice of fractions is the assumption that $A - B = C - D\implies A = C$ and $B = D$, which is demonstrably untrue generally.

Comment: (+1) And here I always thought that $\pi =22/7$.  Now I realize that $\pi =3.14$ instead.  Joking aside, I'm incredulous that papers such as the one referenced by/in the OP are taken as credible.  I recall years ago newletters/papers that circulated that "debunked" the special theory of relativity.   Oh, well.

Answer (score 4):

The paper is incorrect (and frankly nonsensical garbage). The fact that they say $\pi = 22/7$ seems like this might have been a joke paper, or the author might actually be an uneducated rando online, which raises the point that this journal is a completely unreliable source.